# Contact List from Sharepoint Group

Tags: groups, contacts

I am trying to create a contact list which is automatically generated from the users in a SharePoint Permissions Group within SharePoint 2010. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it is, look at this [Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/0564090a-07ef-4e6d-835a-a1b97f4c38a4/)

or

this [Video showing how to create contact list for sharepoint 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qh7jZfo_Jy0)

**EDIT**

Just got what you wanted to do

> If the idea is to just use that list as a web part, then i suggest you
>   to look at Site Users web part and add the web part to the landing
>   page, this web part allows you to configure the SharePoint groups that
>   you want it to be shown. The functionality of this web part is to list
>   down all the members and also provide presence information using which
>   you can send email, instant message and also get to see the
>   information about the users from exchange server.

Source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/bbea25c0-ccfe-45fa-b233-a12ddd17f297

Comment: Perfect, last link was exactly what I was after. Thank you.